# Determine $\langle x,y: x^2=y^2, xyx=y \rangle$

Tags: group-theory

We have a finitely presented group $G = \langle x,y: x^2=y^2, xyx=y \rangle$. It is easily shown the orders $|x|,|y|$ of $x,y$ are divisors of $4$, with $|x| = 4 \Leftrightarrow |y|=4$ and $|x| \leq 2 \Leftrightarrow |y| \leq 2$. To what generally known group is $G$ isomorphic?

Comment: The group is $Q_8$. Try to prove that every element can be written as $x^iy^j$ with $0 \le  i \le 3$, $0 \le j \le 1$, and hence $|G| \le 8$.